# How to add paragraphs or texts in the google doc template, using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, attributes, google-docs

I'm new to script language and I have been struggling to code the following function.

The purpose of the code is to do the following:

1. obtain data from the google sheet, in an array
2. create a new document, which will be a copy of pre-existing template google doc
3. find a specific location of the document and insert the data obtained
4. reformat specific text being added depending on the value

For example,

1. data array would look something like this
   data array = [[object1, object1 type, object1 description], [object2, ....]]
2. 

master google doc template would look something like this

Title1
paragraph 1

Title2
paragraph 2

.
.
.
.

script uses this template to create a new document (copy)

3. find title2.
   if a condition meets to insert text, then adds data at paragraph 2, and edit formatting such that it would look

Title1
paragraph 1

Title2
**[object1]:** object1
object1 description **in red colour

**[object2]:** object2
object2 description **in red colour
.
.
.

so i'm completely fine handling the data. but I have absolutely no idea how to change the format of the texts im editing

it appears that google doc api contains setattributes function, which i tried to integrate into my code, but i have no idea how it works and how to get it work.

please help!

### here is my code

```
function addData() {

data // array of data collected from google sheet, created from different function
doc // document created for edit
userform //sheet where the data is created from (dynamic sheet that changes pending my input)

var body = doc.getBody();
var targetLocation = body.findText("Title2");

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText("\n");
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText(data[i][0]);
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText("\n");
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText(data[i][1]);
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText("\n");
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText(data[i][2]);
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText("\n");
}
```

so far it seems to work, but i cannot get
body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText(data[i][0]); into BOLD

body.targetLocation.getElement().appendText(data[i][2]); into underlined red colour text

Comment: Perhaps this article will help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199564/google-sheets-apps-script-how-do-i-loop-through-replacetext-and-pull-values-fro

Comment: thanks for the reply. but im completely fine getting datasets and such. i just want to change the format of the text im inserting.... maybe i dont understand the google doc api very well

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot imagine your current situation and your expected result. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Have you read the documentation [Class Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) which has n specific script example for setting text as a Bold, but also covers a bunch of other `set` methods for various formats.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert text at specified position in google doc using google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70136422/how-to-insert-text-at-specified-position-in-google-doc-using-google-apps-script)